# turtle triangles, and user input. python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, input, turtle-graphics

I am trying to get this to draw a circle of triangles after asking the user for colors. the triangles come out fine but fill black. I suspect the error is somewhere in the "for i in range" section near the bottom.

```
import turtle
def draw_triangle(side_length):#triangle def
    for x in range (3):
        turtle. left(120)
        turtle. forward(side_length)                   
    return None

def jump(distance):#jump definition
    turtle. penup()
    turtle. forward(distance)
    turtle. pendown()
    return None

def color_triangle(side_length, color):#makes the triangle color filled
    turtle. fillcolor()
    turtle. begin_fill()
    draw_triangle(size)
    turtle. end_fill()
    return None
color_a= input("choose a color for the first triangle ")
color_b= input ("choose a color for the second triangle ")
color_c= input("choose a color for the third triangle ")
back_color= input ("choose a color for the backround ")


my_colors= []

if color_a not in my_colors:
    my_colors . append (color_a)
if color_b not in my_colors:
    my_colors . append (color_b)
if color_c not in my_colors:
    my_colors . append (color_c)
color_number = 0
size= 75
move= 80
for i in range(10):
    the_color = my_colors[color_number]
    color_triangle(size, the_color)
    color_number= color_number +1
    if color_number >= len(my_colors):
        color_number=0
    jump(move)
    turtle. left (35)
turtle.bgcolor (back_color)
```

Comment: I don't see any `for i in range`. And please get rid of the spacing after the `.`, thank you.

Comment: scroll down, its the start of a line after move=80

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not *using* your colors when you call `turtle.fillcolor()`:

Update your `color_triangle` function to this:

```
def color_triangle(side_length, color):
    turtle.fillcolor(color)  # See here! Actually set the fill color!
    turtle.begin_fill()
    draw_triangle(size)
    turtle.end_fill()
```

Note in the [documentation for `fillcolor()`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/turtle.html#turtle.fillcolor) that if you call it without arguments, it actually returns the current fill color. Not what you wanted, in this case.